# is possiable write variable '${properties.${params.deployed_region)_env_region}' in Jenkins groovy

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, properties

Hello am getting loading variable from propeties file in jenkins pipeline am defing varibles in properties file

```
Mumbai_env_region: ap-south-1
N.virginia_env_region: us-east-1
```

here Mumbai is choice parameters

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'deployed_region',
            choices: ['Mumbai', 'N_virginia', 'Singapore'],
            description: 'Note: user can opt for deployment environment'
        )
    }
    stages {
       stage ('Prepare properties ') {
          steps {
            script {
              properties = readProperties file: "jenkinfiles/aws-properties/${params.deployed_region}.properties"

              }
            }
          }
        stage  ('echo test') {
          steps {
              sh """
               ls
               cd jenkinfiles
               echo '${BUCKET_NAME}'
               echo '${properties.${params.deployed_region}env_az}'
               echo '${properties.env_timezone}'
               echo '${properties.INPUT_env_region}'
               echo '${properties.N_virginia_env_region}'
              """
            }
        }

    }
}
```

i want be execute sh script like this

```
echo '${properties.${params.deployed_region)_env_region}'
```

but am geeting  _env_region Such No propery error

but am geeting  _env_region Such No propery error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using the dot notation try the following.

```
def propValue = properties["${params.deployed_region}_env_region"]
```

---

Updated Full Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'deployed_region',
            choices: ['Mumbai', 'N_virginia', 'Singapore'],
            description: 'Note: user can opt for deployment environment'
        )
    }
    stages {
       stage ('Prepare properties ') {
          steps {
            script {
              properties = readProperties file: "jenkinfiles/aws-properties/${params.deployed_region}.properties"

              }
            }
          }
        stage  ('echo test') {
          steps {
            script {
                def propValue = properties["${params.deployed_region}_env_region"]
                  sh """
                      echo '${propValue}'
                  """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its printing all the file not value

Comment: am not scripted pipeline am using a declarative pipeline how can I use def function i try this $properties.["${params.deployed_region}_env_region" ] its printing wgole file

Comment: @MahaboobBashaMD Use the code within a script{} block.

Comment: i used def propValue = "properties[${params.deployed_region}_env_region]" starting pipeline 
its printing echo properties[N_virginia_env_region] with properties data

Comment: @MahaboobBashaMD add your full pipeline to the original question.

Comment: upadted pls help me out